# JBoss-Spring web application development process is so slow

Tags: spring, jboss

Our team is developing a JBoss-Spring web application. The development follows this flow:

1) make local changes in the project's code (Java classes, HTML, JS code and different configuration values)

2) build the project locally

3) deploy it to a locally set JBoss server

4) the local server makes connections and quires to a remote database, which we are enabled to connect to 
    by a VPN.

5) quires results come back from the remote database and used by the services and controllers, 
    ultimately reaching the front-end.

As you can notice, this process takes a lot of time waiting between the build - deployment - database quires every time I want to add a few lines of code.

is this process wrong ?, are there other methods ?

Thanks.

Comment: Points 4 and 5 shouldn't be part of your development process, that's just the application's runtime. If you're using it to validate your code changes, consider using automated testing instead, which could be run locally and/or by a CI server

Answer (score 0):

Few addons you can consider if not done already

- Changes to HTML, js, css and properties file you can do directly **inside deployment folder.**
- Java file changes need a build and restart. You can configure **Automatically publish** in your IDE. This will reduce time for manual building and copying file to Jboss.
- If you can have **local DB** request/response time will reduce drastically.

Comment: We use JSP framework in our front-end work, which uses values presented by the Beans and objects of the backend, so a simple modification in the front-end code won't do it. Do you have suggestions for this case ?